# Not Able to Access to Specific Values of Array of Dictionary inside a List in Python

Tags: python

Can you pleaser take a look at this code and let me know why I am not able to access the value of set of dictionaries in a list?

```
cars = [
{
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 2016
  },
  {
  "brand": "Toyota",
  "model": "Corrola",
  "year": 2010
  }
]
print(thisdict["brand"])

for car in cars:
    for brand in car.items():
        print(brand["brand"])
```

Comment: `car.items()` gives you an iterator of `key, value` pairs representing each item in the dictionary.  If you just want to print the brand, you don't need that second `for` loop - just use `print(car['brand'])`.

Comment: The Toyota model is called Corolla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the second loop.

```py
for car in cars:
  print(car['brand'])

Ford
Toyota
```

Answer (score 2):

You have **list of dictionaries**, not 'set of dictionaries in a list'

So inside `print` function access dict by index and then by key. Also remove nested loop:

```
cars = [
    {
        "brand": "ford",
        "model": "mustang",
        "year": 2016,
    },
    {
        "brand": "toyota",
        "model": "corrola",
        "year": 2010,
    },
]

print(cars[0]["brand"])

for car in cars:
    print(car["brand"])
```